# screen mess when change video on rtmp

Tags: video, ffmpeg, rtmp

1. when I use "ffmpeg -i" to probe video info， the infos below will be shown (take 2 examples)

   ```
   Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 600x352, 281 kb/s, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 59.94 tbc
   Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 532 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50 tbc
   ```

   What does the "avc1" mean？why the first doesn't shown?

   Will it be "screen mess","no sound" or "no image"  when switch the video that is        publishing to rtmp server if the contiguous video encode by different codec?
2. How to switch video publishing to rtmp smoothly ？
   I use nginx-rtmp-module，set "live on"，and use "ffmpeg -re" to publish video.
   My method to switch video is to "pkill ffmpeg", and start another "ffmpeg -re" process.
   If the contiguous videos encode by different codec，it maybe "screen mess","no sound" or "no image". What can I do to solve it?
3. Are there any experiences(about tools,switch videos,how to choose encoding)  when doing  live video?

Answer (score 1):

avc1 is the codec avc (Advanced Video Codec) is just another name for h.264. It is also known as mpeg4 part 10. If you switch from on encode to another, the first IDR AU must contain the SPS/PPS for the new stream. And the player must be able to support reconfiguring the encoder mid stream for it to play smoothly.

Comment: thanks very much,now I uniform the encoding of all the videos, Is there any problem  of "'pkill ffmpeg' and start another 'ffmpeg -re process' "?